# How to fix drag marks on wooden floor?

Tags: repair, hardwood-floor, scratches

We just moved out of my in-laws.
Unfortunately the movers left long drag marks on the floor.

These are not deep, only at the surface. I.e. no gouges.

What is the best way to hide these marks or fix this?

[image: drag marks]

Comment: sand down the floor and refinish it.

Comment: Seems crazy to redo the whole floor for some few scratches. I would try diluted oil based stain that matches. If this floor was prestained, the mfgr probably has scratch repair sticks. If it was finished in place, then someone knows what the stain was.

Answer (score 2):

A small amount of a good quality hardwood floor wax should hide those scratches.  I mean like a paste type wax, something that is solid at room temperature.

Furniture polish would hide the scratches, but the oils would make the floor dangerously slippery. So a solid type wax prevents the oily problem.  You may need to warm a small amount of the wax, so that it soaks in.  But test it first on a 1" part of one scratch, to be sure this is the right path, as it could make the scratch darker.  So test the repair on a small section before applying to the entire scratch.

A second option would be to apply the same finish to the scratch that is on the floor in the first place.  To do that you may need to contact the flooring manufacturer, or if it was finished after it was laid, you will need to get that info from the contractor that finished it.

Comment: alternatively a small amount of boiled linseed oil (BLO) wiped on to soak into the actual scratched bits, then wiped off, will accomplish a similar effect.